# Log-linearization with first-order Taylor approximation

Tags: macroeconomics, log-linearization

I am having trouble with a log-linearization replication that I stumbled across in the appendix of the Chari, Kehoe & McGrattan paper "[Business Cycle Accounting](http://users.cla.umn.edu/%7Eerm/data/sr328/tex/appendices/appendix.pdf)". More specifically the model's market condition [A.2.1 in p.7] is given by:
$$\hat{c}_t+g ̂_t+(1+g_z )(1+g_n ) \hat{k}_{t+1}-(1-δ) \hat{k}_{t}=\hat{k_t}^θ (z_t l_t )^{(1-θ) },$$

where the $\hat{}$ sign denotes a detrended variable. The paper suggests that the above is log-linearized around the steady state, with detrended consumption given approximately by:
$$c ̂ \log⁡c ̂_t ≈\hat{k}^θ (zl)^{(1-θ) } [θ \log⁡\hat{k}_t +(1-θ)(\log⁡z_t +\log⁡z_t  )]-(1+g_z )(1+g_n ) \hat{k}\log⁡\hat{k}_{t+1} +(1-δ) \hat{k}\log\hat{⁡k}_t -\hat{g}\log⁡{g ̂_t }$$

which can be found in page 8. I am approaching this by applying the exponential function in every variable:
$$e^{\log\ {\hat{c}}_t}+e^{\log{\widehat{\ g}}_t}+\left(1+g_z\right)\left(1+g_n\right)e^{\log\ {\hat{k}}_{t+1}}-\left(1-\delta\right)e^{\log\ {\hat{k}}_t}=e^{\log\ \left[{\hat{k}}_t^\theta\left(z_tl_t\right)^{\left(1-\theta\right)}\right]}$$

and then applying a first-order Taylor approximation for each detrended value. For example:
$$F\left(\widehat{c}_t\right)=F\left(\widehat{c}\right)+\left.\frac{\partial e^{\log\ \widehat{c}_t}}{\partial log\ \widehat{c}_t}\right|_{\widehat{c}_t=\widehat{c}}\left(\log \widehat{c}_t\ -\log \widehat{c}\right)=\ 0+e^{\log \widehat{c}}\ \log \widetilde{c_t}
 =\ \widehat{c} \log \widetilde{c_t}$$

Note that in the paper, the log-linearized version uses a $\hat{}$ instead of $\widetilde{}$. I assume that this is purely a notational, yet confusing, matter or I am missing something really big here. My approach seems to produce a good chunk of the log-linearized result, however I am having trouble replicating $\hat{k}^θ (zl)^{(1-θ) } [θ \log⁡\hat{k}_t +(1-θ)(\log⁡z_t +\log⁡z_t  )]$.

I would appreciate if someone could provide a pointer or two as to what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome! Can you please check the hats, tildes (if there are any), and all the terms more generally? Also how are the *g* variables defined?